# Does the database inspector in Android Studio require you to query the database before it shows the schema of a database?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-room

I am working on a simple app with a database file I got from somewhere else. I couldn't get the database to show up on the database inspector.

I checked to see if the database was empty by using VSCode but it wasn't empty. Finally I added the functionality to fetch all rows in the database in the repository and the DAO. And then I added these lines of code

in the UI State (called searchState in my app)

```
val allAirports: List<Airport> = emptyList()
```

in the View Model

```
init {
        getAllAirports()
    }

fun getAllAirports() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            searchState = searchState.copy(allAirports = airportRepository.getAllAirports() )
        }

    }
```

And what do you know, the database showed up on the database inspector.

To test if querying the database is what caused the schema to show, I removed the `init{}` block. When I ran the app again, the database showed but the tables did not. Furthermore, the database was marked as "closed"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view the table data in the database inspector while the database is OPEN only. So, what I did was, I added a breakpoint for a line of code after the database is open (in the code) and before it's closed (in the code). I could see the data in the tables in the data inspector.

But an important thing to note is: **before** you run the app in the debug mode, have the database inspector tab open.

Comment: what does being "open" mean?

Comment: Database open meaning when you open the database to query/insert/update/delete data.

Comment: makes sense. when i queried the database at the app start, the database remained visible throughout. Do you know what makes it move to a closed state?

Comment: Ideally you should close the database/connection after it's operation is complete, otherwise there will be memory leaks. Probably, the database/connection closes, when the object that references it goes out of scope.